# How to avoid database-deadlock occurring while storing & retrieving data same time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms, database-deadlocks

We developed a windows application, the application used like as regular application works; gathering huge information, processing on it, and generating reports...And to store Data we used SQL Server. For reports we used Crystal Reports.

There are more than 150 employees in our office using the application. Most of them are  Data Entry operators. So while Data Storing suppose anyone tries to generate report, application stopped working  & deadlock occurs. There are different threads created for storing information and different threads for retrieving the same (Or generating reports).

So the question is how to avoid dead lock situation, because Storing data & generating reports is continuous procedure can't ask to store data first, then process on it and then generate reports...

How to do both things simultaneously i.e. storing and retrieving data?
Is there any way so deadlock won't occur?

Whatever suggestions or query related to this are welcome..

**UPDATE**

In this scenario, Is using *Views* helpful?

Thank You!!

Comment: The real question is, **who** *Favorited* this question

Comment: How about using DB transaction to prevent dirty read/ write and deadlock?

Comment: DB Deadlocking is a rabbit hole of potential problems and fixes. There is plenty of information about the possible causes and possible solution. However, we cannot give you reliable advice or solve your problem with this amount of information. As such this question is too broad

Comment: The first answer is good indexing :)  The server knows how much data to lock based on what index it is using.  For example, if your report is based on all records for one date, then if you have an index on that date the server will be able to lock exactly those records.  If you're not writing the same records by date at the same time, you should avoid problems.  If you can't make such indexes that clearly discriminate between records reading and writing, there are ways to force reads that ignore any locks - if you're willing to report data that maybe just changed.

Comment: as @TheGeneral said, it is a big question though...  it can include many aspects of good database setup,  so your question may not be a great fit for the site because there isn't a simple, direct answer

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100%, talking about DEADLOCKS as opposed to normal, standard LOCKS. Deadlocks only occur when the engine detects two (or more) processes can NEVER complete due to holding locks that the second process needs to access, and vice versa. Sometimes it can be as simple as checking the logic of the SQL Code/Stored Procs and figuring out if you really need to be holding locks on "other" objects. Absolutely NOT saying this is "How you fix all deadlocks" but it may be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, with ODBC connections, Crystal Reports uses the highest database isolation level the driver supports, which is Read Committed. You can add a registry key to instruct Crystal to use a lower isolation level.

Here is a document providing full instructions: 
[1216415 - How to change the isolation level for an ODBC connection in Crystal Reports?](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1216415)

Answer (score 2):

1. i would have to different databases, one for receiving data and processing and the other one to hold the reporting data.
   -Business rules that allow dirty reads, then create a snapshot where data is sync from inserted data to the reporting database.

   - Business rule no dirty reads, then synchronize as the data is inserted and straight away insert to the reporting database.
2. The table that gets populated should not be the one that is used for reporting.
3. You can you transactions but it will make the reporting take longer on the wait period.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn on `Read Committed Snapshot Isolation` in your sql server, so that writers do not block readers. But readers cannot read records written until they are commited.
In other words, dont block readers but also dont do dirty reads

here is a great article about it
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/#comment-2220427

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to avoid database deadlock.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```